# How to use jQuery to hide and show divs

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div called 'info' that I want to be displayed when a button is clicked.

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<div id="toggle">
Test
</div>
```

Basically I would like to use jQuery to reveal it with a sliding feature but I don't know how. I can find most of the code online and see snippets, but I don't actually know WHERE to put most of it, could someone please walk me through what and where I would need to put the relevant bits of code (from scratch) to get this working? Thank you.

Comment: It may be a good idea to take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***CSS***

```
#toggle {
  display: none
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').on('click', function() {
     $('#toggle').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

***A little explanation:***

- `$('button')` is the selector to the `button` tag.
- `$('button').on('click',` is for bind click event to `button`.
- the second parameter of `on()` here is callback handler and code within it will execute after click to the `button`.
- `$('#toggle')` is the selector to the `div` with `id=toggle`.
- `$('#toggle').slideToggle()` will make a sliding (up-down) effect to the `div` when button click.

---

#### Note

You should do your code within jQuery dom ready function. Which is like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
})
```

in short

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

As these are JavaScript code, so you need to put them within `<script>` tag. for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('button').on('click', function() {
         $('#toggle').slideToggle();
       });
    });
</script>
```

But, if you write this code to an external file then you have to include that file within `<head>` tag like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src_to_script"></script>
```

---

#### According to comment

*Is it possible to make the button disappear when it is first clicked?*

Yes, possible. Try like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').on('click', function() {
     $(this).hide(); // disappear the button after first click
     $('#toggle').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you set the div's `display` property to `none`

Comment: +1 and as the OP seems to not know where to put the code, I would like to add, that this should be wrapped in a `<script>`-tag and be placed somewhere on the page (I would say within `<head>`, but on the bottom of the page it's fine too).

Comment: Very good explanation. I would vote again, if I could. :) Maybe it's worth mentioning, that the tag-selector selects all `<button>`-tags (in this case) and stores it in an array. So, when having **multiple buttons** on a page the click handler will be attached to all of them. In this case the JavaScript would break, because all buttons trigger the `#toggle`-element. So an update in this case could be using jQuery's `.next()`-method like this: `$(this).next().slideToggle();`.

Comment: I would also suggest to do it like @Sanior Sarkar wrote: Hide the content-divs with JavaScript. The advantage is, that users who have JavaScript disabled will still see the content.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Is it possible to make the button disappear when it is first clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this way too:

[Here is jsFiddle to examine](http://jsfiddle.net/DEQ99/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').bind('click', function() {
     if ($('#toggle').is(':visible')) {
       $('#toggle').hide();
     }else{
       $('#toggle').show();
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/n9kre/18/)You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#toggle').hide();
    $('button').on('click', function(){
       $('#toggle').slideToggle();                    
    });
});
```